# Prevent users bypassing security using web addresses

Tags: oracle-apex

After the user has logged in; I have security on page 1 (homepage) of an Apex application which prevents unauthorized users getting any further. Once the user has logged in, it goes away to an apex authorization group and checks whether their name is in the group. If it isn't, it says...you shall not pass.

However if an **authorized** user copy's the web address of page 3 (view employee salaries), and gives it to an **unauthorized** user, they can use it, it redirects them to the login page, they login, and there in to that page!

To get round this as a temporary measure i setup each page to have the same authorization group as on page 1. This works but surely there must be a simpler way to manage this?

E.g. User enters the web address, it redirects them to the login page and once they are logged in it doesnt work as they are not part of the group?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution; there is a something called 'Deep Linking' under the security tab in the Application's properties. I have now checked this to disabled and it always redirects the user back to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is indeed to set up authorization schemes on objects that have to be screened off. In apex 4.2 however (I believe - don't think this was in 4.1) you can go to "application properties > security" and there is an "authorization" section there where you can set up a global authorization scheme.

Comment: Yeah i also found that last night, I thought the authorization scheme had to be setup for each page, but in the app properties i found that option. Thank you for help.